# Wrong path within plugin files

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm running the latest version of WordPress (3.5.1), hostet with Strato and since yesterday some of my plugins are not getting the correct path to their files.

UPDATE: It's **not** a Multisite!

All files are still on the server and haven't been changed or updated since friday (at this point the site was live without issues). The problem is that the plugins are looking at some kind of internal path which looks something like this: `website/wp-content/plugins/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/123456789/htdocs/website/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.css` so all I get is an error 404 (Not Found)

I cannot locate the problem and I'm not getting any PHP errors or anything like that; only the paths are broken... the plugins are even working, but without images, css and scripts!

Therefore I've deactivated all of the plugins but as soon as I activate them again, I'm running into the same problem.

And finally I've already contacted the provider, but they cannot help at all because it seems to be a problem within WordPress.

UPDATE: I've completely removed all of the plugins, but even if I now download and activate a new plugin the path is broken as mentioned above...

UPDATE2: The wrong path looks like this:

```
domain.com/wp-content/plugins/mnt/web1/a1/12/123456789/htdocs/
/website/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.css
```

instead of `domain.com/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.css`
(actually the second version of the path is working, but **all** of the plugins are calling the first version, even if completely new installed)

UPDATE3: Sorry, I'm not able to go more into detail, because I've no clue what's going wrong, so I'm giving it a try from another perspective: everything is working fine, with the exception of the plugins. The plugins are even displayed in the frontend, but without any CSS, JavaScript or images. The same thing happens in the backend. I can see all of the plugins and manage (install, edit, configure,...) them, but there is no styling. Everything in case of the design seems to call a wrong path. In doing so the first part of the path is okay, and also the last part, but in the middle there are numbers which should normally not be displayed within a frontend path because they are a part of the Strato server root directory.

Comment: By your description, there *had* to be a plug-in update. Isolate the plug-in causing the troubles and update your post with the info. *If* it isn't closed as off-topic until then. (Cause it kinda is.)

Comment: Every plugin I'm going to install is broken as described above (with no other plugins installed). Any idea how to solve/reset this?

Comment: Ok. You *really* have to provide more info. *Which* plugins "are looking at some kind of internal path"? *Where* and *when* is it happening? *How* do you know that "they're not getting the correct path"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your the `WP_CONTENT_URL` is not correct.

This is defined as in ./wp-includes/default-constants.php:

```
 define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content');
```

So check your settings > general > WordPress Address (URL)

You can also try to define the correct `WP_CONTENT_URL` in your wp-config.php:

```
   define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-content');
```

When the above don't help check your .htaccess. Maybe wp-content/ is rewrite to the fullpath.

Comment: Yea, that's it! Even if I've to download and activate all of my plugins again, this fixed the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where in the default-constants.php do you put that code? I tried and got an error. The second option didn't work either.